# Python parsing multiple xml tags

Tags: python, xml, text

I am finding element tree a little overwhelming. I have an xml file and I have two tags that I want to get the content of the tags and make a txt file with. The two tags are

```
<l>...</l>,
```

and

```
<bib>...</bib>.
```

Is there and easy way to simply grab whats in these two tags? I can handle the output fine, I am just shaky dealing with xml in python.

Thanks

Comment: SO people are minusing this question because I don't know how to do something easy? I can add all the code for reading and outputting text files but is that really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML files can be challenging to parse until you get the hang of it. First, you need to access the 'node' to which the tags you want belong. To do this, you need to determine where in the file they are located in the XML's hierarchy.

Assuming both of those tags are not nested deep and are at level 2 of the tree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(filename).getroot()

# The dot represents current nested level from root, else you must include other parent tags here
l_list = []
for node in root.findall("./l"):
    # tag.text is the attribute for the text between the tag
    l_list.append(node.text)

bib_list = []
for node in root.findall("./bib"):
    bib_list.append(node.text)
```

A real-world example involves parsing a Nessus scan file. In that case, the desired findings are nested much deeper. A high-level summary of getting to those is like this (this assumes one host, multiple hosts would be more complicated, as you would enumerate each host for findings):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(filename).getroot()

findings = []
one_finding = {}
ReportItems = root.findall("./Report/ReportHost/ReportItem")
for node in ReportItems:
    for n in ReportItems.getchildren()
        # Save all child tags as dictionary of tag_name:tag_text
        one_finding[node.tag] = node.text
    findings.append(one_finding)
```

I hope this example was also useful in showing how to create a dictionary of tag names and their text, then appending all of them into a list of nested dictionaries in case you need to take it that far with what you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've heard of `Beautifulsoup`, but I believe it's very useful for this sort of task. Of course there are multiple ways to accomplish what you're requesting, I'll explain it using `Beautifulsoup`. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Install: `pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_xml='''<CATALOG>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
</CATALOG>'''

souped=BeautifulSoup(my_xml, 'xml')

>>> print souped.find("COMMON").text  # Finds the first instance
Bloodroot

>>> _commons = souped.findAll("COMMON")  # Returns a list of all instances
>>> print _commons[0].text
Bloodroot
```